# Plot coming out absurd

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AMJ5.png)

Hello,

I'm new to R. Data frame is C. Plot should look like B but it appears as A. What am I doing wrong? It is a microbiome plot. I want sample ids on x-axis and the count of respective bacterial phylum (named as index) on the y-axis. The grids within the plot are supposed to be for 4 different diseases (animal_category).

Your help is appreciated! Thanks.

```
dat %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = sample_id, y = count)) +
 facet_grid(~ animal_category, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
 geom_bar(aes(fill = index), stat = "identity", position = "fill")
```

I tried this. I was expecting 'B' as shown in the picture.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: It looks like you just need to make your plotting window much bigger. At the moment, the legend and axis take up all the space. These stay the same size if you drag the plot window to make it larger. The plots will appear if you do that